# How to create Ref for a div in two dimensional loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref

Here I am trying to pass the ref attribute to div but it is not happening, can anybody help me in resolving this issue

````
 const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

 for (let curRow = 1; curRow <= props.row; curRow++) {
    for (let curCol = 1; curCol <= props.col; curCol++) {
      columns.push(
        <div
          ref={ref}
          style={{ minWidth: `${minWidth}px` }}
          className="el1"
          id={`${curRow}${curCol}}`}
          key={`${curRow}${curCol}${generateKey(curCol)}`}
        >{`${curRow}${curCol}`}</div>
      );
    }
  }```
````

Comment: Are you trying to have the ref point to **all** of the divs? Or is there a specific div you want?

Comment: I want ref to all the div's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want refs to all the divs, then you can't use a single ref, you need an array of them, or a 2d array of them. For example:

```
const refs = useRef<(HTMLDivElement | null)[][]>([]);

for (let curRow = 0; curRow < props.row; curRow++) {
  for (let curCol = 0; curCol < props.col; curCol++) {
    columns.push(
      <div
        ref={(el) => {
          refs.current[currRow] = refs.current[currRow] || [];
          refs.current[currRow][currCol] = el;
        }}
        style={{ minWidth: `${minWidth}px` }}
        className="el1"
        id={`${curRow}${curCol}}`}
        key={`${curRow}${curCol}${generateKey(curCol)}`}
      >{`${curRow}${curCol}`}</div>
    );
  }
}

// used like:
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Element at zero/zero: ", refs.current[0][0]);
}, []);
```

Comment: this is so cool, thanks